# Ошибка в плагине IDFA для react-native

Tags: android, react-native

Плагин брал [здесь](https://github.com/FreebirdRides/react-native-idfa#podfile)
Ошибка:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'PTRIDFA.getIDFA')

This error is located at:
    in Auth (at App.js:8)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
```

Подскажите, как решить?

Код:

```
import { IDFA } from 'react-native-idfa'

IDFA.getIDFA().then((idfa) => {
    setData(idfa);
    console.log(idfa)
})
```

Comment: я думаю стоит добавить код который у вас получился после добавления плагина, и добавить больше подбробностей

Comment: ошибка говорит о том, что IDFA - null